# HTML5 image icon to input placeholder

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, placeholder

I'd like to add an image icon to an input placeholder, like in this picture:
[image]

Please note that this is a placeholder, so when the user starts typing, the icon also disappears.

I came with the following solution for webkit (Safari+Chrome) using `::-webkit-input-placeholder` and `::before`. Unfortunately, the straightforward application to mozilla seems not to work.

So my question is: **is there a cross-browser solution to add an image icon to an input placeholder?**

Solution for webkit:

```
#myinput::-webkit-input-placeholder::before { 
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px; /* adjust icon position */
    left: 0px;
    width: 14px; /* size of a single icon */
    height: 14px;
    background-image: url("/path/to/icons.png"); /* all icons in a single file */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -48px 0px; /* position of the right icon */
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1. You can set it as `background-image` and use `text-indent` or a `padding` to shift the text to the right.
2. You can break it up into two elements.

Honestly, I would avoid usage of HTML5/CSS3 **without a good fallback**. There are just too many people using old browsers that don't support all the new fancy stuff. It will take a while before we can drop the fallback, unfortunately :(

The first method I mentioned is the safest and easiest. Both ways requires Javascript to hide the icon.

**CSS:**

```css
input#search {
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" onchange="hideIcon(this);" value="search" />
```

**Javascript:**

```js
function hideIcon(self) {
    self.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
}
```

---

#### September 25h, 2013

I can't believe I said "Both ways requires JavaScript to hide the icon.", because this is not entirely true.

The most common timing to hide placeholder text is on change, as suggested in this answer. For icons however it's okay to hide them on focus which can be done in CSS with the `active` pseudo-class.

```css
#search:active { background-image: none; }
```

Heck, using CSS3 you can make it fade away!

http://jsfiddle.net/2tTxE/

---

#### November 5th, 2013

Of course, there's the CSS3 ::before pseudo-elements too. Beware of browser support though!

```css
            Chrome  Firefox     IE      Opera   Safari
:before     (yes)   1.0         8.0     4       4.0
::before    (yes)   1.5         9.0     7       4.0
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: @Tim Is there a way to accomplish the exact affect using "Font Awesome"?

Comment: @Robert To some extend, yes. The problem is that you must use a pseudo-element (`:before` or `:after`), or you have to add additional DOM. In order to work either of them, the icon should be visible upon `:hover` instead of `:focus` because the icon is not in the input element this way. Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2tTxE/90/). With JavaScript however, you can activate the icon on focus. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: I thinks in `September 25h, 2013` update, did you means `#search:focus` instead of  `#search:active` as your sample code?!

Answer (score 10):

`CSS:

```
input#search{
 background-image: url(bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-indent: 20px;
}

input#search:focus{
 background-image:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="search" />`
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input[type=text] {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Input with icon:</p>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there's a better answer out there as time goes by but this is simple and it works;

```
input[type='email'] {
  background: white url(images/mail.svg) no-repeat ;
}
input[type='email']:focus {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Style it up to suit.

Comment: But it should disappear when typing starts, not on focus.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tim's answer:

```css
  #search:placeholder-shown {
     // show background image, I like svg 
     // when using svg, do not use HEX for colour; you can use rbg/a instead
     // also notice the single quotes
     background-image url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg>... <g fill="grey"...</svg>')
     // other background props
   }

   #search:not(:placeholder-shown) { background-image: none;}
```