# Angular placeholder image and text

Tags: html, css, angular, input, placeholder

Is there a way to include in a input placeholder an image and text at the same time?

Something like this mock:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636349/how-to-have-an-image-placeholder-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder can be fixed by adding the `placeholder` attribute to the input element.

You can also have the placeholder image only show when the value of the input is not equal to null.

See example:

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <img src="" *ngIf="search != null"/>
</div>
```

Its then up to you to position absolute the image into the correct position.