# How do you use images and styled text in placeholders for a textarea?

Tags: html

I have a design where the designer has chosen to use text and images in a textarea's placeholder.  I was wondering, is this possible and/or is there a trick way to insert images and formatted text as a placeholder?

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any tool....just wanted to know if this is possible at all. I'm just using html/css/angular

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 image icon to input placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761654/html5-image-icon-to-input-placeholder)

Comment: clever usage of javascript - yes. It's no simple task though so you'd need to provide what you've tried. Google things like js visual composer. You're basically feigning a text editor by listening on a field and writing to an element used to represent the contents and not display them as they technically are.