# Adding image in form field yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I need to add image into form field in yii2. I can't find an example for how can I do that.I need to do something like that:
[image]

I know how to add placeholder and do that, but dont know how to add the image.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput()->input('email',['placeholder' => "E-mail"])->label(false); ?>
```

Comment: may be this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13761719/4916039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Easiest way to do it will be with CSS.

```
<div class="input_container">
    <span class="input_placeholder_icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput()->input('email',['placeholder' => "E-mail"])->label(false); ?>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.input_container{
position: relative;
}

.input_placeholder_icon{
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
color: red;
left: 2px;
font-size: 21px;
width: 50px;
}
```

You can change some settings in CSS depending on your need. I have used font-awesome icon in the example.