# How can i add icon in placeholder

Tags: html, css

[image: how can i add this]

I create  a mail form and i want to add an icon in placeholder as like as the picture below.
How can i add this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761654/html5-image-icon-to-input-placeholder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 image icon to input placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761654/html5-image-icon-to-input-placeholder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check this link [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaanhaitojahanhai/61y93wfd/)

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Search, search, search and search! -->
<input type="search" name="search" placeholder="search" rel="search" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-mobile-ui-set/512/letter-message-email-mail-20.png);
    background-position: 10px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    padding: 10px 5px 10px 20px;
    text-indent: 20px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;

    width: 200px;
}
```

How to add awesome icon in placeholder, 
Please check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaanhaitojahanhai/2eqwckky/)

Comment: is this only way with backgraound image?